# YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS offset to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS offset?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, utc

I'm using the following formula for the date and time:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 9, 2), MID(A1, 6, 2))+TIME(MID(A1, 12, 2), MID(A1, 15, 2), RIGHT(A1, 2))
```

However, I don't know how to keep the offset as once the formula above is in place, the offset is removed.

Comment: some examples would be nice.

Comment: 2017/01/03 04:48:26 +0100 is the original value. The information that's getting lost is the '+0100'. This could be a static value (+0100 for all entries) or it could vary

Comment: Adding the offset will turn the date time back into a string. `01/03/2017 04:48:20 +0100` is not a time format that is recognized by excel.  Do you want that string or do you want to make the time adjustment so: `01/03/2017 05:48:20`

Comment: I need the string to be displayed along the date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=TEXT(--(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)),"MM/DD/YYY HH:MM:SS") & " " & RIGHT(A1,5)
```

This will return a text string in the format you want that **cannot** be reformatted as it is not a true date.  Nor can it be used in any mathematical formulas.  Also, it will sort based on Alpha sort, as in all the years will get intermixed if sorted as `"01/02/2016"` comes before `"01/03/2015"` in an alphabetic sort.

[image]

Comment: Scott, you rule. Thanks a lot for the help; that works perfectly!!

Comment: While this verifies that the text-time has correctly been converted to a true time (and then back again), it could also be `=text(--left(a1, 10), "mm/dd/yyyy")&right(a1, 15)` since nothing is being done to the time or UTC offset but ultimately this is just a few less characters to type.